# Is it possible to alter Math Equations in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

Take this array of math expressions, which are NOT strings:

```
let eqs = [ 1+n, 2+n, 3+n]
```

Is it possible to loop through these equations and modify them WITHOUT evaluating them in javascript somehow?

```
eqs.map(eq => eq + 1)
```

...and return this:

```
// [ 1+n+1, 2+n+1, 3+n+1]
```

Is something like that even possible at all? Doesn't have to be `.map()` just using that as an example. Doesn't have to be that syntax, i just can't imagine what the syntax for something like that might be is all...

Been googling around but I haven't found much yet...but I am getting the feeling that this might NOT be possible...is that the case?

Thank you for any assistance :-)

Comment: Is `eqs` an array of strings? If so, you just need to iterate over them and concatenate another string to each.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point:

```js
let eqs = [ "1+n", "2+n", "3+n"]
let modeqs = eqs.map(eq => eq+"+1")
console.log(modeqs);
[0,8,15].map(n=>console.log(modeqs.map(s=>(new Function('n','return '+s))(n))))
```

The **updated** snippet now contains a part that  converts each formula into a function and then executes it in a `.map()` structure.

Alternatively you could start with and manipulate actual functions:

```js
let eqs = [ n=>1+n, n=>2+n, n=>3+n]
let modeqs = eqs.map(fn => eval(fn.toString()+"+1") )
console.log(modeqs);

[0,8,15].map(n=>console.log(modeqs.map(fn=>fn(n))));
```

The last example uses `eval()` which by many is seen as a possible security risk. So, please think about where and when you want to use it.

Comment: so, when they are strings...is there any way to convert them back into math expressions WITHOUT evaluating the expressions? The idea is the expressions would be generated in one function, and then the generated expression arrays would then be evaluated in another expression when they finally receive the values for the variables in the expressions...

Comment: I updated my answer. Unfortunately it is not easy to read (too many parentheses) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```js
let eqs = ['1+n', '2+n', '3+n']
console.log(eqs.map(eq => `${eq}+1`))
```

If you want another things . Comment below.

Comment: So, I want the array items to remain unevaluated math expressions, rather than strings. I want what is returned to be: [1+n+1, 2+n+1, etc...] but for them to NOT be strings, and to also NOT be evaluated to a number...Does that make sense? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template literals (Template strings)](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Demo :**

```js
let eqs = ['1+n', '2+n', '3+n'];

let res = eqs.map(eq => `${eq}+1`);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: is there a way to turn the strings back into math expressions after altering them as strings? I need them to be expressions so they can be evaluated into another function later on...